# React Tic Tac Toe Tutorial Error ( this.handleClick is not a function)

Tags: reactjs

I have gone through the tutorial twice, and both times I get to adding the "handleClick" it tells me this function does not exist. I have looked back at the code I entered before and cannot find where I have gone wrong. Everything worked fine until this point.

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        className="square"
        onClick={() => this.props.onClick()}
      >
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    }
  }
  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return ( // each square is being created by calling the rendSquare funcion passing the value
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board />
        </div>
        <div className="game-info">
          <div>{/* status */}</div>
          <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// ========================================

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Game />);
```

I would love to move on, but I need some help.

https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#setup-for-the-tutorial

Comment: The Board class has no method called handleClick but you call it in renderSquare

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to continue down the tutorial to finish making the handleClick method. At the state you stopped handleClick had yet to be defined if you keep following the tutorial your board class will look like this:

```
class Board extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      squares: Array(9).fill(null),
    };
  }

  handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = 'X';
    this.setState({squares: squares});
  }

  renderSquare(i) {
    return (
      <Square
        value={this.state.squares[i]}
        onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    const status = 'Next player: X';

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="status">{status}</div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(0)}
          {this.renderSquare(1)}
          {this.renderSquare(2)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(3)}
          {this.renderSquare(4)}
          {this.renderSquare(5)}
        </div>
        <div className="board-row">
          {this.renderSquare(6)}
          {this.renderSquare(7)}
          {this.renderSquare(8)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I should have gone on. After each step it worked so that through me off.

Comment: It happens, I have done the same thing. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the method `handleClick()` in your class `Board`.

Here the implementation of that method as is described in the Tutorial you've linked:

```js
handleClick(i) {
    const history = this.state.history.slice(0, this.state.stepNumber + 1);
    const current = history[history.length - 1];
    const squares = current.squares.slice();
    if (calculateWinner(squares) || squares[i]) {
      return;
    }
    squares[i] = this.state.xIsNext ? 'X' : 'O';
    this.setState({
      history: history.concat([{
        squares: squares
      }]),
      stepNumber: history.length,
      xIsNext: !this.state.xIsNext,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed handleClick function on `Board` component.

There is usage for this function `onClick={() => this.handleClick(i)}`, but it is not defined.

You should define that function on `Board` component.

```
handleClick(i) {
    const squares = this.state.squares.slice();
    squares[i] = 'X';
    this.setState({squares: squares});
}
```

And in addition, that tutorial seems to be old one.
Please try to learn React with hooks.